# How do I fix this broken CPAN and Perl installation

Tags: centos, perl

My Perl and cpan installation is broken. The perl version is shown below and this command executes and runs fine.

```
>perl -v
This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
(with 34 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

However when I attempt to run cpan so as to install a perl module, cpan returns this error,

```
> cpan
Fcntl object version 1.11 does not match $Fcntl::VERSION 1.13 at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 213.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/CPAN/FTP.pm line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/CPAN/FTP.pm line 6.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/CPAN.pm line 27.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/CPAN.pm line 27.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/App/Cpan.pm line 183.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/App/Cpan.pm line 183.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/bin/cpan line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/cpan line 8.
```

And when I ran the shell version of CPAN again I get the same error. It appears that  the Dynaloader.pm version has some conflict with a previous installed

```
version or something. 

> sudo perl -MCPAN -e shell
    Fcntl object version 1.11 does not match $Fcntl::VERSION 1.13 at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 213.
    Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/CPAN/FTP.pm line 6.
    BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/CPAN/FTP.pm line 6.
    Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/CPAN.pm line 27.
    BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/CPAN.pm line 27.
    Compilation failed in require.
    BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.


> perl -V
Can't undef active subroutine at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/Config_heavy.pl line 1418.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib64/perl5/Config.pm line 79.
```

1. How do I fix the dynaload conflict and error?
2. Why does perl -V return the compilation failed error?
3. Do these errors mean that the perl installation is broken?

Thank you.

Comment: I would advise you telling the whole story. Aborted upgrade?

Comment: I now suspect it could be a faulty upgrade. This is a shared server with an offsite root administration.

Comment: Have you got a PERLIB or PER5LIB variable defined? Failing that, which I think it is the case, If in a Debian system, I would try firstly `apt-get install --reinstall perl`. Both the perl binary and cpan belong to the `perl` package.

Comment: I am on a Centos 7. echo $PERLIB and echo $PER5LIB gives an empty line s or no output at all. Meaning that they are undefined?

Comment: The current situation resorted  from running a  yum reinstall perl  command. This seems to have broken the perl installation.

Comment: If is fine to have PERLIB/PERL5LIB undefined. As for reinstalling packages in CentOS, I do advise waiting for a comment of  someone that uses it everyday (I do not)

Comment: Recommend reinstalling perl and using `cpanm`